# Record of unique values in the array

Tags: c, arrays, unique

I need to add code that will remove duplicate words, when checking (for example, in the text there are several words 'book' and it displays them as duplicate words like -  book book) that are output when compiled. The dictionary is given in like 140 000 words.
Please tell me how to perform check for the uniqueness, so that unidentical words are written to the 'uniq' array

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage* b, const struct rusage* a);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: speller [dictionary] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // structs for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // determine dictionary to use
    char* dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // try to open text
    char* text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];

    //The variable fp contains the literary text
    FILE* fp = fopen(text, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH+1];

    //uniq_array
    char uniq[300][50];

    //count no uniq words
    int countsUniq = 0;

    // spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
    {
        // allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // we must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // update counter
            words++;

            // check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);


            // prepare for next word
            index = 0;
            // print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                //here takes place check for uniqueness and record to an array
                misspellings++;
                for(int j = 0; j < 300; j++){
                    if(strcmp(uniq[j], word) == 0){
                        countsUniq++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(countsUniq == 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
                        if(strcmp(uniq[i], "") == 0){
                            strcpy(uniq[i], word);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                countsUniq = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
       printf("%s\n", uniq[i]);
    }

    // check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(fp))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // close text
    fclose(fp);

    // determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n",
     time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    return 0;
}

/**
 * Returns number of seconds between b and a.
 */
double calculate(const struct rusage* b, const struct rusage* a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}
```

On the output I am receiving the list in the form of some words and symbols which should not get there, some lines are shown empty, I also do not know why:

```
nonproprietary
s
F
IS'
MERCHANTIBILITY
unenforceability




Q@
<
=
@
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: for comparing strings in C you should use strcmp

Comment: if(strcmp(uniq[misspellings], word) != 0){
    uniq[misspellings][j] = word[j];
 } this is not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compering strings is typically done via library function `strcmp`. String cannot be compared via `==` operator.

Also, string cannot be assigned by `=` operator.

```
uniq[misspellings][j] = word[j]; // it will not work
```

Use `strcpy` to copy strings.

This is a simple program to illustrate above concepts. Is can help you to understand your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 30
#define ROWS    5

int main(void) {

    char word[LENGTH+1] = "word";
    char uniq[ROWS][LENGTH+1] = { "eva", "buba", "word" , "1235",  "stop"};

    for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){

        if(strcmp(uniq[j], word) == 0) // find word
        {
            printf("We have found: <%s>\n", word);
            // replacing with "hello":
            strcpy(uniq[j], "hello");
        }
    }

    printf("Strings in uniq:\n", word);
    for(int j = 0; j < ROWS; j++){
        printf("%s ", uniq[j]);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
We have found: <word>                                                                                                                         
Strings in uniq:                                                                                                                              
eva buba hello 1235 stop
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried to remake your code for my own, but as a result I get scribbles/hieroglyphics, when outputting an array.